# Frequency based switching

Tags: signal, frequency, communication, switching

I have two square waves of different frequencies (f1 and f2) and two circuits (ckt1 and ckt2). I want to design a circuit such that on the input when f1 square wave comes, ckt1 gets activated/turned ON and when f2 square comes, ckt2 gets activated/turned ON. I am looking for a frequency-based switching between circuits. What ideas would not involve FFT or a microcontroller (because I am looking for a circuit-level implementation with low-processing capacity)?

Comment: What are the frequencies? What are the peak values? Do they both have 0.5 duty-cycle? Is it possible to make them have non-square (i.e. duty-cycle higher or lower than 0.5).

Comment: f1 is 1kHz and f2 is 5kHz. It is possible to make them as clock pulses ('1' => 3.3V and '0' => gnd (0 V)). The duty cycle of both the signals is around 5%. It is a requirement for the other part of the design that the duty cycle and the frequency stay the same.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with new information rather than putting it in comments.

Comment: If f1 and f2 are fixed and the duty is fixed then this is a relatively easy task - depending on how demanding you are. eg At 1 kHz and 5% t_hi is 50 uS, and at 5 kHz t_hi is 10 uS. By examining each high pulse you can make a decision in not more than 1 ms , and as little as about 200 us.

Answer (score 0):

Use a high-pass or low-pass filter with cutoff at 3 kHz, followed by an envelope detector. Add a comparator at the output of the envelope detector to convert the analog output to a digital signal.

Answer (score 0):

If f1 and f2 are fixed and the duty is fixed at 5% then this is a relatively easy task - depending on how demanding you are.

At 1 kHz cycle time is 1 ms and 5% duty cycle makes t_hi = 50 uS.
At 5 kHz cycle time is 200 us and 5% duty cycle makes t_hi = 10 uS.

By examining each high pulse you can make a decision in not more than 1 ms
and in as little as about 200 us.